# Sorting a list with a comparison function that doesn't follow 'strict weak ordering'

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of 10 items. I would like sort them in a particular manner.

For eg. the items are A1, B, C1, A2, A3, F, G, C2, H, A4

Rules are

- C should always come before A
- B should always come after A
- All the other item should preserve their order.

So after sorting the list should be in this order
C1 C2 A1 A2 A3 F G H A4 B

I am trying to use C++ `std::stable_sort()` method to achieve this. In my program all the items are instance of a structure 'SItem' which got a member 'type' to idicate its category(A, B etc). My comparison function looks like this

```
bool CompareItems(SItem const& item1, SItem const& item2) 
{
    if (item1.type == A && item2.type == C)
        return false;

    if (item1.type == B && item2.type == A)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

From my understanding of `stable_sort`, it requires the comparison function to follow 'strict weak ordering'. Obviously my method doesn't follow that, so I cannot use the stable_sort. Is their sorting algorithm available to achieve this type of orders?

**Complete code**

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

enum ItemType
{
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H,
};

struct SItem
{
    SItem(ItemType t, int i) {
        type = t;
        index = i;
    }

    ItemType type;
    int index;
};

//do not follow strict week ordering
bool CompareItems(SItem const& item1, SItem const& item2) 
{
    if (item1.type == A && item2.type == C)
        return false;

    if (item1.type == B && item2.type == A)
        return false;

    return true;
}


int main()
{
    std::list<SItem> lstItems = { {A, 1}, {B, 1}, {C, 1}, {A, 2}, {A, 3}, {F, 1}, {G, 1}, {C, 2}, {H, 1}, {A, 4} };
    std::stable_sort(lstItems.begin(), lstItems.end(), CompareItems);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say `list`, do you mean a `std::list` or a general sequential data structure like `std::vector`?

Comment: I am okay to keep the items in a list or a vector. Basically the container doesn't matter here.

Comment: afaik strict weak ordering is just what you need to sort a collection in a unique and meaningful way. If your comparison isnt a strict weak ordering you will have cases where you cannot decide if an element A should come before or after a second element B

Comment: Are you fine with changing rules to "C before everything" and "B after everything"?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot - One does have to wonder if transitivity really is required for a stable sort in this case. So long as the B's and C's move in relation to the A's (but not in relation to each other). Any resulting order should fulfill the OP's requirement.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot - No. Other than rule 1 and 2 order should be preserved.

Comment: @StoryTeller maybe, but standard requires strict weak ordering and strict weak ordering requires transitivity. Otherwise it would be UB from language point of view.

Comment: Can `A4` be placed before `F G H`? You say the order *should* be this way. But it's impossible if you need to keep order "everything other" vs all `A`s  and all `B`s. Imagine `B X A`. `B>X`, `X>A`, `A>B` cannot be all satisfied. Your classes and criteria are not clear.

Comment: Actually, never mind. A partial ordering can break the stability of the stable sort IINM.

Comment: Why does F G H come before A4?

Comment: Is stability otherwise a requirement?

Comment: `std::stable_sort` also does not work with `std::list` because it requires random access iterators.

Comment: "_All the other item should preserve their order._" Order relative to what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## This is not a sort

At least not as `std` library defines its sorts.

You just want to move some elements around.

4 steps:

- Find the first A.  This is where we want to shove the Cs.
- Stable partition all C to be right before the first A.
- Find the last A.  This is where we want to shove the Bs.
- Stable partition the Bs to be right after the last A.

All Cs before the first A remain stationary.  All Bs after the last A remain stationary.

Cs keep their relative order.  Bs keep their relative order.  Both move the least possible to generate the guarantee you require.

Everything that isn't a C or a B keeps their relative order.

Code:

```
template<class It, class IsA, class IsB, class IsC>
void do_it(It s, It f, IsA a, IsB b, IsC c){
  auto first_a = std::find_if(s,f,a);
  first_a = std::stable_partition(first_a,f,c);
  auto last_a = std::find_if(std::make_reverse_iterator(f), std::make_reverse_iterator(first_a), a).base();
  std::stable_partition(s,last_a, [&b](auto&&x){return !b(x);});
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/943762ab67db980b).

With enough spare memory, the above is O(n).

Of course, this could simply be done in one line:

```
std::stable_partition(s,std::find_if(std::make_reverse_iterator(f), std::make_reverse_iterator(std::stable_partition(std::find_if(s,f,a),f,c)), a).base(), [&b](auto&&x){return !b(x);});
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: This is a topological sort, so I'd argue with your semantic complaint. In fact, you could use a standard O(E+V) topo sort algorithm to solve the problem in O(n) because in this case every vertex has exactly one edge.

Comment: @rici Corrected.  As for O(n), the above is n lg n simply because we want stability, and the `std` stable partiion algorithm has only so much "swap space"; when it runs out of swap space they degrade to n lg n.  I believe said swap space is limited by `new` failing with a `bad_alloc`, basically.

Comment: i think that is true. Indeed, the topo sort algo needs a stack (O(n) space) so it is not different. (And might be necessary to construct the DAG, but I think the space could be recycled.) Afaik there is no topo sort in the standard library but Boost has one.

Comment: @rici What would be the time complexity to construct the DAG for a sequence of items? And how can every vertex have one edge if each C has an edge to each of the four A's?

Comment: Oktalist: the last C connects to the first A. The remaining Cs and Bs connect to the next item of the same kind, and everything else connects to the next element which is neither C nor B. Finally, the last A additionally connects to the first B. In all, there are no more than N edges and construction time is O(N) (although you don't actually need to construct it since you can easily compute the adjacencies on the fly once you know where the first and last A are, which still requires an O(N) scan but only requires O(1) space.)

Answer (score 8):

It is not a strict weak ordering, but it is a [partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). An algorithm for sorting by a partial ordering is called a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), like this naive implementation:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Compare>
void stable_toposort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Compare cmp)
{
    while (begin != end)
    {
        auto const new_begin = std::stable_partition(begin, end, [&](auto const& a)
        {
            return std::none_of(begin, end, [&](auto const& b) { return cmp(b, a); });
        });
        assert(new_begin != begin && "not a partial ordering");
        begin = new_begin;
    }
}
```

It partitions the sequence so that all the elements that are not greater than any other element are moved to the front. Then it takes all the remaining elements and partitions them in the same way, until there remain no more elements to be partitioned. Its complexity is O(n²) comparisons and O(n) swaps.

Then we need to fix the bug in the comparison function:

```
bool CompareItems(SItem const& item1, SItem const& item2)
{
    if (item1.type == C && item2.type == A) return true;
    if (item1.type == A && item2.type == B) return true;
    return false;
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://ideone.com/Tp5Ywc)

For reference, an unstable version would use `partition` instead of `stable_partition`.

Comment: `C < B` is not necessary. Suppose there were no `A`s at all; in that case the minimally permuted result is the original list; adding the `C < B` relation could induce unnecessary permutations. So I'm not sure what bug you are referring to.

Comment: @rici True, but without `C<B` it is not a partial ordering. What is it supposed to do when the function induces `C<A && A<B && B<C`? That's a contradiction. The second bug is that it returned `true` when neither argument is less than the other.

Comment: Let my try that again. A partial ordering corresponds to a directed acyclic graph; because the graph is acyclic, it cannot be the case that `a < b < c < a` (or, for that matter, `a < b < a`). It is often convenient to define the PO as the transitive closure of the graph, in which case it is necessarily transitive. But the standard topo sort algorithm, as well as your naive topo sort, do not require the transitive closure; they will work fine on the adjacency relationship. So `B < C` is not necessary (it will automatically be the case *if there is an `A`*)...

Comment: ... Remember that partial orders are *partial*. So if the comparator returns `true` that indicates the existence of a relationship, but if it returns `false` that indicates the non-existence of a relationship; it does not imply a reverse relationship. For that reason, you are 100% correct to modify the comparator to return `true` in specific cases and `false` by default.

Comment: @rici Very interesting point about the adjacency being sufficient. I removed the redundant line from the comparison function so now it won't generate unnecessary permutations, as you said.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is some sort of stable topological sort. Your DAG is that Cs point at As point at Bs.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236027/585411 for a description of a reasonably efficient algorithm to implement the topological sort that is lowest in lexicographic (in your original list) order.  Its output in your case would be:

```
C1, F, G, C2, A1, A2, A3, H, A4, B
```

Thinking about it that way makes it easy to generalize lots of different kinds of rules that you might have, rather than special casing how this example works.  So long as they don't add up to a circular path, your algorithm will still work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desired algorithm right, it's probably easiest to just split manually into three lists and then splice back together.

```
void slide_bs_and_cs( std::list<SItem>& all ) {
    // Don't touch if no A's found:
    if ( std::find(all.begin(), all.end(),
        [](const SItem& item) { return item->type == A; }) == all.end() )
        return;

    std::list<SItem> bs;
    std::list<SItem> cs;
    auto first_a = all.end();
    auto after_last_a = all.end();
    for ( auto it = all.begin(); it != all.end();
          /*advanced in loop*/ ) {
        auto next = it;
        ++next;
        if ( (*it)->type == A ) {
            after_last_a = next;
            if ( first_a == all.end() )
                first_a = it;
        } else if ( (*it)->type == B ) {
            bs.splice( bs.end(), it );
        } else if ( (*it)->type == C ) {
            cs.splice( cs.end(), it );
        }
        it = next;
    }
    all.splice( first_a, cs );
    all.splice( after_last_a, bs );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a non strict weak ordering is that the order is not enough to define the sorted list. With the input `A1, B, C1, A2, A3, F, G, C2, H, A4` you proposed the output `C1 C2 A1 A2 A3 F G H A4 B`. But in fact, B came before H in original list and now comes after which is not conformant with a stable sort. If you wanted to preserve B < H, you could get the following list:

```
C1 C2 A1 A2 A3 F G A4 B H
```

but here it is the A4 < H that has been broken.

To build a stable sort, you have to define a strict weak ordering. To obtain the list you propose, this order could be used:

- C comes before A
- B comes after A
- all other letters are equivalent to A

In that case, the compare function becomes :

```
bool CompareItems(SItem const& item1, SItem const& item2) 
{
    if (item1.type == 'C' && item2.type != 'C')
        return true;

    if (item1.type != 'B' && item2.type == 'B')
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, you could try to specify an algorithm that accepts a non weak strict ordering, but you will have to specify what happen when you have this original list
`X Y Z`, `Z < X`, `X,Y` and `Y,Z` non comparable: do you want `Z X Y`, `Z Y X` or `Y Z X`? In fact it depends whether Y should be processed as equivalent to X or Z or... And then wonder what could happen in more complex use cases...